# Is $7+13k$ ever a perfect square (for $k$ in $Z$)? (Part of a question regarding modulus)

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

The original question is whether or not $2x^2 ≡ 1 (mod 13)$ has an integer solution.

---

The way I solved it is:

Let $y = x^2$.

We can conclude that $y = 7+13k$ for $k$ in $Z$. I assert that $7 + 13k$ is never a perfect square.

---

However, I don't know how to prove it. Any suggestions on how to? Any other ways of solving this question (perhaps using residue classes)?

Comment: How did you conclude that using the Euclidean Algorithm? I can prove it by multiplying both sides of the congruence by $7$ and getting $x^2 \equiv 7 \pmod {13}$

Comment: @Ovi $13 = 2(6) + 1$ --> $1 = 13 + 2(-6)$ --> $2(-6) ≡ 1 (mod 13)$ --> $13-6 = 7$. Therefore, $y = 7 + 13k$

Comment: That's not Euclid's algorithm.  But ... I don't care.  But I think that was Ovi's point.

Comment: @fleablood it isn't? whoops sorry about that

Comment: It's no big deal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In $\mathbb F_{13}$ one has
$$2x^2=1\iff x^2=2^{11}=7 \space \text{because } 2\cdot2^{11}=1$$ But **$7$ is not residu quadratic modulo $13$**. In fact, by the law of quadratic reciprocity, we have $$\left(\frac{7}{13}\right)\cdot\left(\frac{13}{7}\right)=(-1)^{\frac{7-1}{2}\cdot\frac{13-1}{2}}=1$$ But $$\left(\frac{13}{7}\right)=\left(\frac{-1}{7}\right)=(-1)^{\frac{7-1}{2}}=-1$$ Consequently $\left(\dfrac{7}{13}\right)$ must be equal to $-1$

Comment: thanks! I prefer this answer

Comment: Dear Piquito, what is $\mathbb F_{13}$? Does it stand for the field of integers $\pmod {13}$?

Comment: Dear Ovi, $\mathbb F_p$ is the standard symbol of the finite field having $p$ elements where $p$ is a prime number so you are right with your second question. This is the smallest field of characteristic p (see in Wikipedia about characteristic of a field if you don't know this concept.

Answer (score 3):

If $a \equiv b\mod 13$ then $a^2 \equiv b^2 \mod 13$ where $b = 0,\pm 1, \pm2, \pm 3,... \pm 6$

Just test them out one after another $0^2 \equiv 0; 1^2 \equiv 1; 2^2 \equiv 4; 3^2 \equiv -4; 4^2\equiv 3; 5^2 \equiv -1; 6^2 \equiv -3 \mod 13$.

So $a^2 \not \equiv 7 \mod 13$ ever.

There's probably a slicker way to do it but that's pretty rock solid.

====

But I am concerned how to prove this if these were large numbers....

Read up on [Quadratic Residues](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_residue).

($q$ is a *quadratic residue* mod $n$ if $x^2 \equiv q \mod n$ has a solution.)

In the wikipedia article:

$x^2 \equiv 7 \mod p$ if and only if $p \equiv \pm1, \pm 3,\pm 9\mod 28$.

So that's the specific answer.

But if we avoid rote recital, a basic result will be:

If $p$ is prime then there are, including $0$, $\frac {p+1}2$ quadratic residues and $\frac {p-1}2$ quadratic non-residues.

So there are $\frac {p+1}2 = 7$ quadratic residues mod $13$ and $6$ quadratic non- residues.

(Also worth noting if $p \equiv 1 \mod 4$ as $13$ is, then $q$ is a quadratic residue if and only if $-q$ is.  [And if $p \equiv 3 \mod 4$, the exact opposite is true; $q\ne 0$ is a quadratic residue if and only if $-q$ isn't.]  But I didn't find this that helpful.)

As $0, 1,4,9,16\equiv 3, 25\equiv 12, 36\equiv 10$ are obviously $7$ perfect squares, then those are the seven quadratic residues.

And $7$ is not among them.

There's quite a bit to learn.  But there's nothing wrong with punching a fist through a wall.

Comment: Write a program for it :D?

Comment: I don't understand this process at all. Why is $b$ up to $+-6$

Comment: All numbers are congruent to one of $-6,-5,-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4,5,6$... of if you want to $0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12$ but as $7,8,9,10,11,12$ are congruent to $-6,-5,-4,-3,-2,-1$ those are the same thing.

Comment: ahh ok i understand. thanks